# Kotlin jetpack compose desktop in Jar does not work

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a project on Koltin, I’m using the compose desktop template in intellij idea, I’m trying to compile it into a Jar via Artifacts by selecting jar -> form modules with dependencies . In the Bild tab, select bild artifacts and click bild under the file.

An error appears in the console

```
`Kotlin: The provided plugin androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler.
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void registerProjectComponents(com.intellij.mock.MockProject, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.CompilerConfiguration)' of interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar.
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:671)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.registerExtensionsFromPlugins(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:162)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.configureProjectEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:572)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:192)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:107)`
```

I don’t really understand how to solve this.

gradle.properties

```
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version=1.8.20
compose.version=1.4.1`
```

It’s also worth adding that if I go to the main file and press the start button (green play button), then everything works without errors

I tried to change the SDK in project settings -> project, changed it to corretto-18, kotlin sdk, openjdk-20.

I also tried replacing gradle.properties with this

```
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version=1.8.0
compose.version=1.4.1`
```

Comment: you might be using an old version of intellij idea. please update it to latest for upto date project templates